# I want to disable the dayclick event

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I want to disable the `dayClick` event.
`select` event always fires after the `dayClick` event. I want to stop it.
Can I disable the `dayClick` event?

```
$(function() {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar
({
  defaultView: 'agendaDay',
  defaultDate: '2018-04-07',
  editable: true,
  selectable: true,
  eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'agendaDay,agendaTwoDay,agendaWeek,month'
  },
  views: {
    agendaTwoDay: {
      type: 'agenda',
      duration: { days: 2 },
      groupByResource: true
    }
  },

  resources: [
    { id: 'a', title: 'Room A' },
    { id: 'b', title: 'Room B', eventColor: 'green' },
    { id: 'c', title: 'Room C', eventColor: 'orange' },
  ],
  events: [
    { id: '1', resourceId: 'a', start: '2018-04-06', end: '2018-04-08', title: 'event 1' },
  ],

  select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view, resource) {
    alert("select");
  },

  dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view, resource) {
    alert("dayClick");
    return false;//not work
    //jsEvent.preventDefault();//not work
    //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');//not work
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is part of my code and this does disable the day click

```
$("#datepicker").fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left:   'cbRefresh,prevYear,prev,next,nextYear,cbMonth',
                center: 'title',
                right:  '' //month,basicWeek,listWeek
            },
            height:             750,
            firstDay:           1,
            weekNumbers:        true,
            editable:           true,
            eventLimit:         true,
            defaultView:        'month',
            displayEventTime:   false,
            weekends:           uweekends,
            views:  {
                month:  {
                    eventLimit: 3
                }
            },
            dayClick: function(seldate,jsEvent,view) {
                //window.location.href=entryScreen+"?dt="+seldate.format();
                return false;
            },
```

**return false**, does work.  Have you just tried deleting this block:

```
dayClick: function(seldate,jsEvent,view) {
                //window.location.href=entryScreen+"?dt="+seldate.format();
                return false;
            },
```

One thing to make sure of, well for me it made a difference, is to make sure you clear the cache after each change.

Comment: If you comment dayClick, a select event will occur.
Even just one click!
Also, the default view is "agendaDay".
Thank you.https://codepen.io/nextageot/pen/yrprWx

Answer (score 0):

**Just remove the dayClick function block if return false not working**

Comment: I have already tried, but select will enter the event. The view mode is "agendaDay".
I want to avoid that select is called by one click.Please check the code below.
https://codepen.io/nextageot/pen/yrprWx

Comment: I think its not clear to me. what you really need to do?

Comment: I understand your meaning. But I want to distinguish between clicks and selections. If it can not distinguish, I just give up. .